# How to find string's word start with some character?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, string

I want to get value of string's like follow.

If `string's word start with some character` like `("This is world").match(/^wo/g);` It should return `false` But, i want it's `true`.
Because string has one word which start from `wo`.I don't want to execute `line or string` start with `wo`.

Please any one know using `Regex` how to check whole line's words check start with `XYZ`.

NOTE : I already Know that Line splitting with white-space and than after check every word start with `XYZ` But I don't want to split any line.

Thank you

Comment: `^` marks the beginning of the string. There is no beginning with `wo`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

firstly .match does NOT return boolean

you want regexp.test

```
(/\bwo/g).test("This is world");
```

\b matches a zero-width word boundary - see [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp)

Comment: Can you also please comment here ? `End of every word validation `

Comment: what does `End of every word validation` mean?

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```
var str = "The rain in SPAIN stays mainly in the plain"; 
var res = str.match(/ain/g);
```

Comment: not one of those words starts with ain - yet you get a match - the question is hard to understand, but not that hard

Answer (score 0):

A capturing or non-capturing group will do this job.

```js
alert(/(^|\s)wo/.test("This is world"));
alert(/(^|\s)wo/.test("This is bar;world"));
```